# Error de autoload.php en laravel

Tags: laravel, composer

hice un pull de un repositorio de git, al tirar un php artisan serve o en la web con laragon me da el mismo error:
´´´Warning: require(C:\laragon\www\confluencia-api\public/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\laragon\www\confluencia-api\public\index.php on line 34

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\laragon\www\confluencia-api\public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:/laragon/etc/php/pear') in C:\laragon\www\confluencia-api\public\index.php on line 34´´´

Ya trate de hacer un composer install y composer update en la carpeta raiz pero tambien da error, AYUDA..!

Comment: *Ya trate de hacer un composer install y composer update en la carpeta raiz pero tambien da error* ¿y cuál error te da al hacer eso?

Comment: Tal vez puedes borrar el composer.lock y todo el directorio /vendor y luego ejecutar nuevamente composer install --prefer-dist y cuentanos a ver que pasó.

Comment: Ya se arreglo, tuve que eliminar el composer.lock e hice todo de nuevo y funcionó, gracias.. <3